# Writing parallel ``zip`` using ``Control.Parallel.Strategies``

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I've recently discovered the (frankly amazing) parallelism that's obtainable from judicious use of `Control.Parallel.Strategies`. I was curious if it is possible to write something like a parallel version of `zip` with the tools provided by `Control.Parallel.Strategies`. What I'm thinking of would have the following signature:

`parZip :: Strategy (a, b) -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`

Conceptually, it would work similarly to `parMap`, except applying an operation over two lists in parallel rather than just one. I'm not sure how I would go about writing this though. Would someone be able to tell me how I would go about this (if I can)?

Answer (score 5):

I may be missing something, but isn't that just:

```
parZip :: Strategy (a, b) -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
parZip strategy as bs = zip as bs `using` parList strategy
```

And yes, `Control.Parallel.Strategies` is really something special.